# How to use workflows that are embedded in Alfresco Content Services in ADF or ACA?

Tags: alfresco

I'm using Alfresco content app (ACA) and I want to develop a user interface to replace share (partially).

However, when I wanted to access workflows that are embedded in Alfresco community services (ACS) I could not, because those services belong to Alfresco process Services (APS). Is there any way to access and use workflows and tasks embedded in ACS from ACA without using APS?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I started (last year) looking into something similar (with ADF), I don't have access to the code anymore sorry. Plus I don't have any experience with ACA so I'm not sure what that entails. However:

You're probably going to have to call the repository workflow APIs directly and create your own UI components. Have a quick look at this [list of rest API](https://api-explorer.alfresco.com/api-explorer/?urls.primaryName=Workflow%20API#/)s as a guide. Start with the process definitions, then the processes active, then the individual tasks and move on from there.

Comment: thank you for sharing that, I can create the UI component with angular, the problem is in calling the API, when I tried to use webscript it didn't work and apparently it is deprecated from newer versions of ADF. If you have any suggestions on how I can call the API I would be grateful

Comment: Again, this was a year ago (and only done once) so my memory is a little vague. However, I'd suggest looking at this [link](https://www.alfresco.com/abn/adf/docs/content-services/components/webscript.component/) and maybe use the tutorial for ADF to make sure authentication is happening and you've actually got a backend repository running (change ports to point at your instance of Alfresco or run a local one) etc.  Then look into some of the code that Alfresco uses behind the scenes in some of their utilities (Github) for pointers.

Comment: sorry for the late replay, I have alfresco community up and running. I will see if there is any way to call an api from ADF without using ADF services. Thank you anyway

Comment: "MAY" be of some help, not sure how much Alfresco experience you have with calling repository webscripts. But you can find a simple one to test with to start, have a look at "http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/index/all"* to find a simple GET in the repo. Then have a look at ADF's method https://hub.alfresco.com/t5/application-development/how-to-call-remote-api-from-adf/m-p/230535 to call them.
*Change domain/port as required or use a development version launched from either Maven or Eclipse.

Comment: I'm new to alfresco. I will try it, thank you,